# getfacl says my unprivileged account should be able to read the contents of a dir, but it can't

Tags: shell, permissions, freebsd, acl

I'm probably missing something glaringly obvious..... but I can't see it.

I have an ordinary directory on FreeBSD, controlled by NFSv4 ACLs. The ACLs say I can list its contents; but I can't.

Here's the `getfacl` output on the problem dir and its parent + grandparent:

```
 # getfacl /mnt/data_dir/working_dir/
# owner: root
# group: wheel
group:data_managers:-w-pDd--------:-------:deny
everyone@:r-------------:-------:allow
group:data_managers:rwxpDda-R-c---:fd-----:allow
owner@:--------------:fd-----:allow
group@:--------------:fd-----:allow
everyone@:--x-----------:-d-----:allow

  # file: /mnt/data_dir
# owner: root
# group: wheel
owner@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
group@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
everyone@:r-x---a-R-c---:fd-----:allow

  # file: /mnt
# owner: root
# group: wheel
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

I `su` as the newly created account having the ACL issue. This account is not the owner of any relevant dirs, nor a member of `wheel` or `data_managers`, so its only rights stem from the "everyone (world)" permissions/ACLs.

```
 $ su -f restricted_user
 % id
uid=1100(restricted_user) gid=65533(nogroup) groups=65533(nogroup),4003(restricted_users)
 % pwd
/mnt/data_dir/working_dir
 % ls
ls: .: Permission denied
```

I don't get it. The world permission on that dir is `everyone@:r .....` (inheritance downward to subdirs for "x" but not "r"). `r` should give worldwide rights to read the contents of `working_dir`. It's not a member of `data_managers` and if it was, the deny ACE isn't denying `r` or `x`. I can traverse to it. But I can't read its contents.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now explored and reproducible, filed as a bug in FreeBSD ACL evaluation:

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228538